# Detecting user abort/navigation websockets

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I'm experimenting with websockets and would like to detect if a user has navigated away from the page to the PHP stream script from running. Everything else is working fine.

Everything I try to do does not stop the PHP script from running (using Xampp locally).

I'm currently working with javascript's `beforeunload`, and PHP's `connection_aborted()`, `connection_status()` and even `file_exists()` (which is the only one that works currently!!!).
Until the script exists or I restart apache I cannot reload the page but it's the abort detection that I have to get working. Firebug reports the socket script has aborted but PHP just keeps ion running. Any help appreciated.

My javascript looks like this

```
function socket_open(){
    if(!!window.EventSource){
        var websocket = new EventSource('./ajax/progress.php');
        websocket.addEventListener('message', function(e){
            var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log(data);
        },false);
        $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
            websocket.onclose = function(){};
            websocket.close();
        });
    }
}
```

And my PHP is like this.
./ajax/progress.php

```
function get_task_progress(){
    $output = array();

    //conditionally create some output

    if(!empty($output)){
        echo 'data: '.json_encode($output)."\n\n";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    sleep(1);
    if(!connection_aborted() && connection_status()==0 && file_exists('1.txt')){
        get_task_progress();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved it but echoing and flushing a no updates status on every request before the test for a live connection

```
if(!empty($output)){
    $tasks_state = $tasks_new;
    echo 'data: '.json_encode($output)."\n\n";
}else{
    echo 'data: '.json_encode(array('e'=>0))."\n\n";
}

ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(1);
if(!connection_aborted() && connection_status()==0){
    get_task_progress();
}
```